# FCKEditor WYSIWYG controls not showing up on ColdFusion 9

Tags: coldfusion, fckeditor

I wrote a CMS that utilizes the FCKEditor library, it has worked flawlessly, but recently has stopped working. Instead of showing all of the WYSIWYG controls it is just being rendered as a simple textarea.

I have not changed anything and it is happening to two different clients on two separate servers.

Does anyone have a clue what might be going on?

Thanks,

JS

Comment: are you using a different browser? do you get any javascript errors?

Comment: Sounds like you are getting a JS error, that is stopping FCK editor from executing.

Can you share a link to the page in question?

Comment: What happens when you go to: [SERVER]/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/resources/cf/images/loading.gif  Do you get a spinning icon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem root problem was with a bug in the FCKEditor code related to Firefox and other Mozilla based browsers.

The problem is on line 47 of fckutils.cfm located in the root of the fckeditor install:

`stResult = reFind( "gecko/(200[3-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9])", sAgent, 1, true );`

Yes that right any gecko browser made after Jan 1, 2010 will fail to match their test.

You can change it to something like this:

`stResult = reFind( "gecko/(20[0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9])", sAgent, 1, true );`

Thanks to Pete Freitag for posting an answer for this. For the complete answer take a look at:

http://www.petefreitag.com/item/737.cfm